# How to stop Designer from generating DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am developing MyDataGridView control with fixed columns and rows.

```
public partial class MyDataGridView
{
     public MyDataGridView()
     {
         CreateColumns();
         CreateRows();
     }
}
```

When I add MyDataGridView onto a Form at design-time the designer is autogenerating more columns - exactly the same columns as created with CreateColumns() in the constructor above. Can I stop the designer from doing this?

```
private void CreateColumns(); // Creates columns of MyDataGridView.
```

Please add this code to a WindowsFormsApplication project, compile and drag MyDataGridView control from ToolBox on a Form1 then run the application. See how the Designer behaves and generates code (Form1.Designer.cs).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyDataGridView : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    {
        public MyDataGridView()
        {
            CreateColumns();
            CreateRows();
        }

        private void CreateColumns()
        {
            for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++)
            {
                this.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            }
        }

        private void CreateRows()
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 6; n++)
            {
                this.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answering would be easier if you posted a bit more of your code.

Comment: The problem is probably in your eventhandlers, check your forms Load eventhandler.

Comment: And to continue on @PaulKertscher´s input: there is always more code to show ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:-

First set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and
cancelling the generation of the column if it's ColumnName equals to the value you can exclude, like

```
 private void MyDataGrid_AutoGenerateColumn(
object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)e.Column.Header == "fieldname")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```